# ASP.Net MVC Bundle linked content files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, file, bundle

I've been trying to reduce the amount of copying and pasting of content files across some of my projects and decided to go down the adding files as links from a central project.

The problem I have now is that the System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.AddFile(string virtualPath, bool throwIfNotExist = true) does not work as the file doesn't really exist in the directory I specified.

Does anyone have any pointers? Or maybe an alternative to linking content files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot access files outside of your web project with the virtual path system and It might hurt when you want to deploy your app.

I suggest to make a custom project for your static content with a custom domain: e.g. static.yourcompany.com and reference all this files from this domain. This also has the advantage that the browser does not have to add the cookies for authentication and tracking to these requests, which might be faster if you have a lot of traffic. You can also open your custom cdn (http://www.maxcdn.com/pricing/) or store the files in azure or amazon aws (which is more or less free for less files and traffic).

Another approach is to make some batch files to keep your content files synced.

Comment: Linked files work when in production as they get deployed and get copied physically, debugging is the issue. Some suggest using MSBuild to sort it out for debugging, but it's too much to make sure that every other developer needs to maintain this too.

Cannot consider CDN at the moment, going to rely on SVN with externals for the time being.